# Confused by passing back *args and **kwargs to a decorated function

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, keyword-argument

I am new to decorators. I want to create a decorator function that checks if the user specified a valid keyword parameter before executing the decorated function. The decorated function takes either two or three keyword arguments. When inside my wrapper function within the decorator function I seem unable to call to my decorated function simply using **kwargs. This is a bit annoying and I feel like I'm missing something.

Where I'm struggling is in the **else** statement in my verify_quantity() method. Why do I have to pass all the arguments back one at a time instead of just passing **kwargs? When I try this I get an UnexpectedArgument error. I understand that it's because **kwargs is going in as a dictionary, but in all the examples I've seen this is how it's done.

```
    @staticmethod
    def verify_quantity(func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            valid_quantities = ['voltage', 'current', 'power']
            try:
                quantity = kwargs['quantity']
                args = list(kwargs.values())
            except KeyError:
                quantity = args[0]
            if quantity.lower() not in valid_quantities:
                gf.report_msg(f'Parameter "{quantity}" is not a valid scalar quantity. Valid options:', level='error')
                for valid_quantity in valid_quantities:
                    print(f'\t   > {valid_quantity}')
            else:
                if len(args) == 2:
                    return func(args[0], args[1])
                elif len(args) == 3:
                    return func(args[0], args[1], args[2])

        return wrapper

    @staticmethod
    @verify_quantity
    def scalar_to_bytes(quantity: str, value: (float, int), num_bytes: int) -> list:
        if quantity.lower() == 'current':
            const = 1e4
        else:
            const = 1e3
        scaled_value = int(const * value)
        min_bytes = (len(hex(scaled_value)) - 2) // 2
        if num_bytes < min_bytes:
            gf.report_msg(f'Minimum bytes required for conversion: {min_bytes}', 'warning')
            num_bytes = min_bytes
        byte_list = list(scaled_value.to_bytes(num_bytes, 'little'))

        return byte_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain how you call `scalar_to_bytes()` so I'm not sure if this is a solution or not. if it does not help you get back on track let me know so I can remove it.

I think from what you describe, you are looking to do something conceptually like:

```py
def verify_quantity(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        valid_quantities = ['voltage', 'current', 'power']
        if kwargs.get("quantity") not in valid_quantities:
            print(f"{kwargs.get('quantity')} must be one of {valid_quantities}")
            return

        func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper

@verify_quantity
def scalar_to_bytes(quantity, value, num_bytes):
    print(quantity, value)

scalar_to_bytes(quantity="voltage", value=1, num_bytes=2)
scalar_to_bytes(quantity="foo", value=1, num_bytes=2)
```

That should give you:

```
voltage 1
foo must be one of ['voltage', 'current', 'power']
```

Comment: Hi, there. Thanks for taking the time to respond. Yes, this is essentially what I'm trying to accomplish. When I structure my functions like yours I get a TypeError:

TypeError: scalar_to_bytes() got multiple values for argument 'quantity'

Comment: Can you give an example of how you are calling that function

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was wrong. The issue was that I re-defined the **args variable within my try/except clause. The type-change caused my decorated function to see an extra argument that I didn't intend. Special thanks to JohnSG for helping me see the light.

The modified code works as intended. Note, that I am no longer unpacking my **args in the try-block:

```html
  @staticmethod
  def verify_quantity(func):

      def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
          valid_quantities = ['voltage', 'current', 'power']
          try:
              quantity = kwargs['quantity']
          except KeyError:
              quantity = args[0]
          if quantity.lower() not in valid_quantities:
              gf.report_msg(f'Parameter "{quantity}" is not a valid scalar quantity. Valid options:', level='error')
              for valid_quantity in valid_quantities:
                  print(f'\t   > {valid_quantity}')
          else:
              return func(*args, **kwargs)

      return wrapper

  @staticmethod
  @verify_quantity
  def scalar_to_bytes(quantity: str, value: (float, int), num_bytes: int) -> list:
      if quantity.lower() == 'current':
          const = 1e4
      else:
          const = 1e3
      scaled_value = int(const * value)
      min_bytes = (len(hex(scaled_value)) - 2) // 2
      if num_bytes < min_bytes:
          gf.report_msg(f'Minimum bytes required for conversion: {min_bytes}', 'warning')
          num_bytes = min_bytes
      byte_list = list(scaled_value.to_bytes(num_bytes, 'little'))

      return byte_list
```